# What is the meaning of public static void main(String[] args)?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args){

}
```

what is the difference between `public static void main(String[] args)` and `public static void main(String args[])`

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. `String[] args` is the same as `String args[]`, just a different notation.

Comment: but second one is misreading  IMO

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yes, I agree. Second one comes from C, first one is more Java like.